# Copy 300MB Data From Server To iPhone

Tags: iphone, copy

i want to copy large data ie... around 1400 files around 500 MB from web server to iphone documents directory. it is taking more than hour .some how i want to reduce the time taken for coping file.

i m using 
code:

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:someURL]];

if([data writeToFile:self.documentsDirectory atomically:YES])
    NSLog(@"File Copied");
```

i m using above code in for loop till no of file ends.
can some one suggest a better way???
i had tried NSOperationQueue and CFFTPURL but doesnot improve performance significantly.

Comment: You mention 300MB of data in the question title, but then 500MB in the question itself... that's a pretty large discrepancy.

Comment: One thing you'd best do is check that there is enough room on the iPhone drive to hold that much data. You're talking about taking up to 5% of drive in one gulp. People really load up their iPhones. 500mb is a non-trivial download on a laptop and the iPhone is not a laptop.

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing this on wifi ? either way turn the data into an archive using tar/zip etc... before transport. It is a known fact that sending multiple files over a network is orders of magnitudes slower than concatenating the objects first.

Comment: it is right now 300 MB but it can goes to 500 MB that's why i mention 500 MB